# Fragment onClick method not working

Tags: android, android-fragments

The click listener in my fragment isn't working properly. I'm not getting any debug messages in my logcat whatsoever from my requestData method, nor my onClick method. I was thinking it was probably due to trying to use activity methods from the fragment, but I don't see any problems with doing that; it also wouldn't affect my onClick debug messages not showing up.

Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public void requestData(String first, String second) {
        Log.d(“Success!”, first + “ “ + second);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);
    }
```

Fragment:

```
public class WelcomeFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{

    private Button mButton;
    private EditText mFirstEditText;
    private EditText mSecondEditText;

    private View v;

    public WelcomeFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        mCalculateButton = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.calculate_button);
        mCalculateButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        mFirstEditText = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.first_editText);
        String first = mFirstEditText.getText().toString();
        Log.d("Button clicked", "mFirstEditText set " + first);

        mSecondEditText = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.second_editText);
        String second = mSecondEditText.getText().toString();
        Log.d("Button clicked", "mSecondEditText set " + second);

        v.requestData(first, second);
    }

}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:orientation="horizontal">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/welcome_fragment"
        android:name="com.example.kent.AnApplication.WelcomeFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

welcome_fragment.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                tools:context=".MainActivityFragment">

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/welcome "
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/welcome_textView"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="68dp"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/first_editText"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/welcome_textView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/second_editText"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/calculate_button"
        android:layout_marginTop="43dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/second_editText"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't set clicked listener. Try below code:

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        mButton = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.your_button_id);
        mButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        return v;
    }
```

If you have some "clicked" events, you have to use if/else or switch on your onClick(); method.

Comment: you mean with setContentView?

Comment: I mean I don't see where you add your WelcomeFragment. Can you update your source code on your question?

Answer (score 0):

Change your `Fragment` code to following:

```
    public class WelcomeFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{

    private Button mButton;
    private EditText mFirstEditText;
    private EditText mSecondEditText;

    private View v;

    public WelcomeFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated (View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        mCalculateButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.calculate_button);
        mCalculateButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick (View v) {
               mFirstEditText = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.first_editText);
              String first = mFirstEditText.getText().toString();
              Log.d("Button clicked", "mFirstEditText set " + first);

             mSecondEditText = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.second_editText);
             String second = mSecondEditText.getText().toString();
             Log.d("Button clicked", "mSecondEditText set " + second);

             v.requestData(first, second);
         }
        });
    }  
 }
```

Comment: It didn't work sadly. I'm not getting any debug messages in logcat.

Comment: changed the 2nd line in `onViewCreated` to `mCalculateButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.calculate_button);` can you try once and see

Comment: I get a compiler error for "new OnClickListener" and for the onClick method.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your **onclick** method, you haven't find the id of that Button on which click has occurred, change your onclick() method code as:

```
 @Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if(view.getId() == R.id.calculate_button) {
    mFirstEditText = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.first_editText);
    String first = mFirstEditText.getText().toString();
    Log.d("Button clicked", "mFirstEditText set " + first);

    mSecondEditText = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.second_editText);
    String second = mSecondEditText.getText().toString();
    Log.d("Button clicked", "mSecondEditText set " + second);

    v.requestData(first, second);
}
```

}

I hope it'll work for you

Comment: hey do one thing register your onClick() listener in fragment onResume() mButton.setOnClickListener(this);